# Hosted WebBrowser control attempts to download Flash content rather than playing it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hosting, webbrowser-control

I am hosting an IE browser control in a simple, .NET winforms app. When I make the control  navigate to certain content on disk, the control attempts to download the file (rather than displaying the content.) The exact same URL when pasted into the IE browser will properly display the swf file in question along with processed XML data that is passed as a parameter.

Abbreviated example of the URL:

```
file:///C:/...SomeSwfFile.swf?dataXML=%3C ... assume well-formed XML here
```

What can i do to get the browser control to behave just like the IE application with that type of URL?

Additional per feedback: HTML files are loaded into the control just fine.

Comment: Does it do the same thing if the file being requested ends in htm? I have a feeling this might be security-related.

Comment: HTML files work fine. But it's not a security issue. I set IE's security to non-existent and the behavior was the same.

Comment: This could be my issue: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/c4a06945-7591-4b0f-ae01-1fec8162cfa8/

Comment: If you'll mainly (or exclusively) be using SWFs, you may want to embed it (or a loader if you have multiple ones). That way you wouldn't have to worry about browser/sandbox issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that i was trying to host a Flash control inside a web browser control built on a x64 dev box. At this point in time Flash doesn't do well in 64 bit processes. When i set the app to build for x86 everything worked fine.